# Powershell thread issues: code executed twice?

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I am having issue with threading and hoping someone can clear this up for me. My thread is returning duplicate entries in an array. I have been going in circles trying to figure out why. Here is the code:

```
$arrayofinfo | Start-RSJob -Name {"Command_$($_)"} -throttle 10   -ScriptBlock {     

     $command = $_
     $array_1 = @()
     $array_1 = Invoke-Expression " & $command" -EA SilentlyContinue
     if(($array_1.count) -gt 20)
     {  
        $array_1 += $command
        $array_1 += $array_1
        return $array_1
     }
} ## end of scriptblock
get-rsjob | wait-rsjob #-Timeout 7
$array_complete = get-rsjob -HasMoreData -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |  Receive-RSJob -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

What is happening is either the $command is executed twice or results are put in $array_1 twice. Somehow... $array_complete is double in size and contains duplicate entries for each entry. HOW?????? Anything else that looks like it can be improved please comment on. thanks.

Comment: `$array_1 += $array_1` Is not this line doubles the array?

Comment: Yes however it would add a NEW entry, resulting from the invoke expression command. It shouldn't add a second duplicate. Or so I think. The examples I found showed to add like this. If this is incorrect, and its the problem, how to get around this? I really do not know.

Comment: Well.. I think Petseral is correct. Changing the return array to $temp and running looks to have repaired that.  Thanks for the eye opener.